# Transform standard normally distributed numbers into arbitrary normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation

I need a random number generator with a normal distribution, with parameterizable mean and standard deviation.  I have only a uniformly distributed random number generator.  By applying a Box-Muller transform to two uniformly distributed numbers in [0,1), I get a standard normal distribution.  However, I've become confused about how to get an arbitrary, parameterized normal distribution by this procedure.

Since you can use a z-transform to change a non-standard normal distribution into a standard one, I thought that I could just use the inverse of a z-transform, and pass the result of the Box-Muller-transformed uniformly distributed numbers into $(x \times \sigma) + \mu$, where $\sigma$ is the desired standard deviation and $\mu$ is the desired mean.  I've become convinced that this is a mistake.  My simulation, using the transformed RNG didn't behave properly (I'm able to compare it with a well-tested normally distributed RNG), and a plot of the transformed distribution doesn't look at all correct.

I think that what I need to do is to do something with the mean and standard deviation *inside* the Box-Muller code, rather than just processing its return value in a simple way.  However, I'm confused about how to do this.

In case it's helpful, here is my Box-Muller code. (It's in the [NetLogo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) language, which may not be familiar, but I think this bit code will be intelligible to anyone with programming experience.)

```
to-report box-muller-random-normal [mn stddev]
  if-else box-muller-cache-exists = 0 [  ; using 1 for true and 0 for false means we don't have to initialize to false in setup; just use default zero init value
    ; cache is unfilled, so compute new pair of values
    let x1 random-float 1
    let x2 random-float 1
    let y1 sqrt (-2 * ln x1) * cos (2 * pi * x2)
    let y2 sqrt (-2 * ln x1) * sin (2 * pi * x2)
    set box-muller-cache y2
    set box-muller-cache-exists 1
    report y1
  ][
    set box-muller-cache-exists 0    ; so cache will be refilled next time
    report box-muller-cache
  ]
end
```

Where would I insert transformations involving the mean and standard deviation?  (`to-report` is NetLogo's function-definition command.  The code using `...cache...` variables is designed to remember one of the values between invocations, generating new numbers only if there is no remembered value.)

Comment: why are you implementing box-muller yourself/by hand??  At a quick glance it looks like NetLogo [has a built-in normal deviate generator](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/random-exponential.html) ... unless you're doing something *not* in NetLogo but have chosen to express your algorithm in NetLogo code (which would be pretty weird ...)

Comment: Right, but [NetLogo Web](http://netlogoweb.org/) hasn't yet implemented it.  I need to make a NetLogo model available to my students now, without requiring them to install NetLogo.

Comment: oh, OK. Makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X \sim N(0,1)$, then $Y = \sigma X + \mu \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. So,
leave the RNG and Box-Muller alone, and when you get the generated
variate, just multiply by $\sigma$ and add $\mu$. You could stick these
inside the Box-Muller code if you really want just simple code by
modifying

`let y1 sqrt (2 - ln x1) * cos (2 * pi * x2)`

to

`let y1 sigma * sqrt (-2 * ln x1) * cos (2 * pi * x2) + mu`

and similarly for `y2`.